# What is the "Valley of Plenty" referenced in "Toss a Coin to Your Witcher"?

Tags: the-witcher

In the Netflix series "The Witcher", S1 E2, Jaskier the bard composes and sings a song "Toss a Coin to Your Witcher" which references the "Valley of Plenty".

What is this "Valley of Plenty" that Jaskier is referring to?

Lyrics from [this reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/netflixwitcher/comments/e72wra/full_lyrics_to_toss_a_coin_to_your_witcher/):

> Toss a coin to your Witcher
>   O’ Valley of Plenty
>   O’ Valley of Plenty
>   O’
>
> Toss a coin to your Witcher
>   And friend of humanity

Comment: The valley surrounded by the mountain's where the elves lived after being expelled from said valley. It was the valley of plenty because it had good harvests, probably due at least in part to the genocidal war fought against the elves, which led to mass burials that enriched the soil. The irony is that the pleasant name and the anodyne stories mask the bitter reality.

Comment: Obviously, the "friend to humanity" bit is very funny as well. He's had his very DNA altered, refuses to call himself human, and to cap it off is a misanthrope. The whole song is supposed to be the very opposite of reality.

Comment: @Adamant, I think your comment qualifies as an answer -- would you like to move it to an answer?

Comment: @Adamant Well, he refuses to call himself human because he is, in fact, not one. His DNA was altered, but he wasn't the one who altered it. It was done so that he could protect humanity from monsters, which he does. He also occasionally protects others for reasons that have nothing to do with money (Duny, for instance). I'd say "friend to humanity" is not especially ironic here, whether or not "valley if plenty" is. I don't have a high opinion of the show's writing, but I think Geralt tends to be presented as mostly a good guy in the books and games as well.

Comment: I think he has a fairly low opinion of humanity, as a whole. That doesn't mean he doesn't see himself as obligated to be moral, as much toward dragons or elves as toward humans. I see that part of the song as very ironic - it's saying that Geralt helps humanity by killing the non-human monsters. In reality, as often as not he helps the "monsters" by killing humans. Geralt doesn't protect humanity from monsters: he protects people from monsters, which is a very different thing.

Comment: Well humanity has two meanings. If you think of humanity as a concept (defining kindness and understanding toward others) rather than a species, then he _definitely_ favours humanity - he will often take the side of a kind "monster" over an unkind human, often to his own detriment. In doing so, he is siding with humanity.

Comment: In the books this region is called "Valley of Flowers" and is very fertile. Looking at differences between serial and books, it could be renamed for better sounding, but it's just speculation.

Comment: @Adamant *In reality, as often as not he helps the "monsters" by killing humans.* - I don't think that's accurate. The parts that are explicitly part of the story 
show him as an equal-opportunity protector if good vs evil, human or not. But part of his character is that he is a Witcher by occupation - i.e. he pays his bills by hunting monsters with contracts on them. In fact, Witchers' code forbids taking contracts on people. I think it's pretty strongly implied that he spends a lot more time killing non-human monsters than human ones.

Comment: @MishaR - Weeeeeell, there's what he *says* he does and is *supposed* to do, and what he actually does. It's true, he doesn't take contracts on humans..but only because he does *that* part *pro bono publico*.

Comment: @Adamant It's how he makes a living, as does every other witcher. I think we can assume he isn't being coy about being one.

Comment: @MishaR - The point, he kills monsters (human or otherwise), because he believes it's what right. Sure, he accepts money to kill the non-human ones, because it helps keep him in coin, but he kills a fair number of the human ones (and the non-human ones, for that matter) absolutely for free. It's not clear that he has any bias toward killing non-human monsters, and it's fairly clear that he wouldn't kill a "monster" (e.g. a dragon or a Sylvan) that wasn't monstrous. It's clear to me that he's not the sort of "friend to humanity" that Jaskier's song implies.

Comment: @Adamant It isn't clear to me that he kills as many humans as he does monsters. In fact, I'm pretty sure there are parts both in books and in the games where he expresses a reservation about killing a human. And, if we do consider the games as part of the canon (I do), then many times you get the option to *not* kill a human, even if it's a bad one. You rarely get that kind of choice in monster contacts - it's usually simply assumed that you're gonna kill it. That implies that killing humans is more distasteful to Geralt. I see your reasoning, but I don't think it goes beyond speculation.

Comment: My answer references **the guy who wrote the song, explaining precisely what the words mean** and I only get one lousy vote. That's what it's like being a Witcher...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's never made explicit, but the Valley of Plenty is the land that the humans took from the elves during what was basically a genocide. That is, the town where Geralt was at the beginning of the episode.

We know it's a valley both because of the topography that we see in the show, and because of the references to the elves as having retreated to the mountains.

> The elves called this Dol Blathanna before bequeathing it to the
> humans and retreating into their golden palaces in the mountains.
>
> <sub>"Four Marks", *The Witcher*</sub>

The "of Plenty" bit is suggested in Filavandrel's assertion that:

> I called it digging a mass grave for everyone I loved.
>
> And now the humans proudly watch these very fields grow, our babies
> fertilizer for their grain.
>
> <sub>"Four Marks", *The Witcher*</sub>

So we know that it's a region that has good harvests, probably enhanced, as Filavandrel says, by all the bodies buried there.

I'm not sure there's any dialogue in the show suggesting that it's the actual name of the region rather than Jaskier's coinage, although the books may indicate otherwise.
It's very possible that this song is meant to be sarcastic, since Jaskier was there when Filavandrel told them the actual history of the region, and Jaskier didn't seem unaffected. Obviously he wants to write a song to earn some money for Geralt, but perhaps he's not above working some irony in.

Indeed, the "friend to humanity" bit is sufficiently ironic that it lends some credence to this interpretation. Geralt is a mutant who appears to have some light contempt for humanity, judging by his insistence that Filavandrel not classify him as human and his general misanthropic character. Practically speaking, as well, he isn't a friend to humanity in the sense in which it would be understood in a world with many other sentient species: he's as likely to kill humans to help a dragon, or to save a cursed knight with a pretty inhuman aspect, or to sacrifice an evildoer to cure a striga, as he is to kill a Black Sun mutant and her gnomes to save human villagers.

Comment: In the books the land is magically fertile and is called "The Valley of Flowers". As I recall the humans took it from the elves because it was already exceptionally fertile.

Bards making romanticized versions of Geralt's exploits is a running theme of the books.

Comment: There's a quote in [this interview](https://ew.com/tv/the-witcher-toss-a-coin-to-your-witcher-anatomy-of-a-song/) that makes it clear that it was named after the land. You might want to add it to your answer.

Answer (score 11):

## A metaphorical Valley of Plenty

While I like @Adamant's answer in that the valley may very well reference the region they are in, I personally believe that it actually references the people he's singing to.

The "Valley of Plenty" are "the people that the Witcher has helped". The whole idea behind Jaskier's songs is to increase the prestige of Geralt and to turn public perception away from "he's a scary mutant Witcher" and towards "he's a helpful guy who solves your problems".

Read in that way, "toss a coin to your witcher, o valley of plenty" translates roughly to "give him some money, you have plenty and can miss a single coin". This is also more obvious in the rest of his song, it describes the things Geralt has gone through 'for humanity' and that he deserves a reward.

> **He wiped out your pest**
>
> Got kicked in his chest
>
> He’s a friend of humanity
>
> **So give him the rest**
>
> That’s my epic tale
>
> **Our champion prevailed**
>
> Defeated the villain
>
> **Now pour him some ale**

The whole idea of Jaskier's songs is to hype up the accomplishments of Geralt because he promised to make him famous and successful. The Valley of Plenty are the people who won't have to face all those hardships because their "friend of humanity" is doing it for them.

Comment: If that were the case, I would think it would be Land of Plenty. It references the people he is singing to, sure, but because they live in the valley he uses that term.

Comment: Anyway, we can see even more irony in this part: Geralt didn't wipe out anyone, and there wasn't exactly a villain to be defeated.

Comment: @Adamant Yeah, Jaskier is obviously lying, but the peasants don't need to know that. The devil that was stealing their grain is gone, but out of their own volition. If the peasants think Geralt fought it and his army of elves, instead of getting captured and convincing them to move, than he likely wouldn't have gotten his payment. The whole idea is to make Geralt seem like the hero the people need. It's a clever song, and it also seems to be why Geralt eventually allowed him to tag along after saying "That's not how it went at all!"

Comment: While I accepted the other answer since that seems more canon, this (answer) was exactly what I was thinking of first as well -- that Jaskier was referring to humanity as the "Valley of Plenty" and asking them to "toss a coin", but I was also thinking, "nah, it can't be that convoluted, can it?"

Comment: Really, it's exactly the same thing as when you go to a concert and the performer addresses the audience as their city name, e.g., "HELLO SAN FRANCISCO!"

Answer (score 3):

It's stated by the song's writer, Jenny Klein, that the valley in the song is the valley in which the bulk of the action takes place in Episode 2.

> Another source of inspiration is the name of the location in which Geralt's story takes place in episode 2. **Translated from an elvish language, Klein says it means "Valley of Flowers or Valley of Plenty." "So I was like, to not even get paid in the Valley of Plenty? Come on! Toss a coin to your Witcher! I got excited about this being a way to draw empathy for the character. So that’s how I ended up coining 'Toss a Coin to Your Witcher.'"**
>
> <sub><sup>[Anatomy of a song: How The Witcher earworm 'Toss a Coin to Your Witcher' was made](https://ew.com/tv/the-witcher-toss-a-coin-to-your-witcher-anatomy-of-a-song/)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 1):

I go for the metaphorical Valley. I think it is quite obvious.
And in the german version of the song "Gebet Gold eurem Hexer, ihr gütigen Menschen" they even show it. It's translated to "Bestow gold to your witcher, you benevolent people"

Comment: This seems to be more of a comment on [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/226146/58193) stating it is metaphorical than an answer to the question because of the opening wording. You make a good point with the German translation find though so it would be better to [edit] this to focus it into more of a standalone answer.